# Media upload ERROR Message Showing in BOTTOM of the page wordpress

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a large file which is exceeding the size limit, that is ok, means should be shown an error. But this error message is showing at the **bottom** of the page. I need to scroll and scroll down to the page then i get the error message. Is there any way to change the location of default message to the top of the page in word press?
Please find an image describing this. http://prntscr.com/ebvvgn